# Gradle fails to resolve dependencies in Android Studio. That Is My Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies

I get this error when I was adding some dependencies to my android studio projects........What Am I doing wrong?

See Code below.  Thanks in advance.

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
        compile 'org.json:json:20141113'
        // This library handles authentication and authorization
        compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-auth-beta22-noconnect-2.20b@aar'
        // This library handles music playback
        compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-beta22-noconnect-2.20b@aar'
        // All other dependencies for your app should also be here:
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    }
```

Comment: post error too along with post , from post `get this error` , which will , check logcat

Comment: @PavneetSingh I don't understand your comment.. What do you mean please?

Comment: post your log cat, and share your build.gradle (module project)

Comment: ok, thanks...I will that

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following code from your app level build.gradle file and put it to your projadct level build.gradle

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this...

1). `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'] , dir: 'libs')`

2). the testCompiler is missing  `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`

add this testCompiler below the compile fileTree like given below-

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'] , dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

and remove

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
```

and paste it in Gradle Project

Comment: Thanks @Shivam, I am still facing the error.  See error below.

Comment: Error:Failed to resolve: com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-beta22-noconnect-2.20b:

Error:Failed to resolve: com.spotify.sdk:spotify-auth-beta22-noconnect-2.20b:

Comment: this show the problem with these to compile Dependencies i.e. compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-player-beta22-noconnect-2.20b@aar' and compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotify-auth-beta22-noconnect-2.20b@aar' check these two might have come mistake with it